# Cheapest path on a checkerboard from A to B. Turning and moving cost differently

Tags: java, algorithm

We have a checkerboard with positive x and y coordinates.

```
0,0  1,0  2,0 ...
0,1  1,1  2,1 ...
0,2  1,2  2,2 ...
...  ...  ... ...
```

We have to find the cheapest path from A to B, given turning costs 100 energy and moving costs 500 each step.

I've looked into the [Dijkstra Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) but I think that's not relevant to my problem.

What would be the easiest solution for this?

Comment: Read up on [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm)

Comment: Mike, I'll read that, thanks!

Comment: The problem is either trivial or not well specified. The cheapest path on a non-obstructed rectangular field is to go horizontally, then vertically (or vice versa); disregarding the initial orientation, it takes 1 turn and `dx+dy` moves.

Comment: Yea, but is that always the cheapest route? Considering turning costs less than moving one step.

Comment: Unless the pieces can "wiggle" to the goal (like, 3.5 turns will progress a piece the equivalent to 1 move), yes, it is always cheapest. Take out your chess board and count for yourself. Now if there are obstacles on the field, it's quite a different matter. @Andreas_D's answer tells you the same thing.

Comment: @gieldl: Yes, it's provably the cheapest route.  Any other route would require at least the same number of steps but with more turning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum number of moves is *always* |X<sub>B</sub>-X<sub>A</sub>|+|Y<sub>B</sub>-Y<sub>A</sub>| and we can do it *always* with only one turn.

Example: move from (1,2) to (4,6):

```
3 moves right: 1500
1 turn:         100
4 moves down:  2000
               ----
               3600
```

We can't do it with less moves, only with more turns.

Comment: Initial orientation might come into play and require more than one turn.  In that case, you just need to either turn, or if you're facing in a direction you eventually need to go, go that way first.  If A, B and initial orientation are random there is a very small chance you will need 0 turns, slightly more than 50% chance you will need 1 turn, and slightly less than 50% chance you will need 2.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the A* algorithm

And to calculate the G cost you could use your values, but i would recommend 1 for moving North, East, South and west. And sqrt(1*1 + 1*1) = sqrt(2) = 1.14 for moving Norht-East, East-South, South-West and West-North.

Good tut (tried my self):

[http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm)

Another good tut when you want more than just a path:
(Path optimizing, and often the methods described in this tut will make the path even faster, this tut will only work if your characters can move in more than 8 directions).

[http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131505/toward_more_realistic_pathfinding.php](https://www.gamedeveloper.com/programming/toward-more-realistic-pathfinding)

Comment: With A* you usually use a hueristic, which is an idealized estimate of distance from the goal that always underestimates (or is exact).  On a board with no obstacles, the heuristic IS the distance from the goal.  A* is therefore overkill.

Comment: I should have said it was without obstacles, sorry. Still thanks though, obstacles might be added later.